# GoogleApi single token for organization users

Tags: google-drive-api, admin, access-token

I would like to be able to authenticate as an administrator of the organization and then receive any every user's data from the DriveApi using **the same** admin token and some sort of user id.

I understand that [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) does something similar, but I do not want to transfer anything, I just want to be able to see users data in a given organization.

For example Microsoft has TenantId which does exactly that. Once admin consents on behalf of the organization, TenantId can be used similar to RefreshToken together with account id to get account's files in the OneDrive.

Comment: I'm not sure that Domain-wide delegation works like that (transfer anything). For example when delegating you service account a domain-wide authority, your service account needs to impersonate one of those admin users to access the Admin SDK Directory API.

Comment: Exactly, I expect admin to authenticate with google, so that I can assume that I already have admin's token at hand without the need for impersonation. I'd like to use this token to programmatically add ServiceAccount's ClientId to the *Authorized API clients* list.

[Manage API client access PrintScreen](https://imgur.com/AKsjD5v)